# Key-value list in Redis

Tags: redis

How can I store collection with key-value pairs in Redis? For example, I want to log time when user tried to login, to some collection. Every user have id, so I want to use it as a key. But I want to store it separatly from other elements, in separate collection

Answer (score 1):

For each user you can have a sorted set. You can use the user id in the name of the sorted set. Just use 1 as the value since you don't need to store something there and use the timestamp as the score.

`zadd 'user:' + uid +':logins' currentTimestamp 1`

With this you can run queries to grab how many times a user tried to login during certain periods with `zcount` etc.